# Does exiting X server kill ongoing processes? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: command-line, xorg, services, xserver

I have an ongoing process running in a terminal while I'm using X server. I'd like to both exit the X server and have my process continue its job.

Is this process going to be stopped if I exit the X server via `sudo service lightdm stop` command?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is yes. If you stop/exit/kill a process, all of its child process going to be stopped.

If you stop the lightdm, you stopped the X, the terminal will be stopped as it's a child of X also the shell and running applications in that shell.

You can use `pstree` to find out if your desired process is a child of `X`:

```
pstree -s $(pidof process-name -s)
```

or:

```
pstree $(pidof lightdm)
```

to see all lightdm childs.

---

How to keep your process ongoing? run it in an other `tty`.

[Start a process on a different tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170063/start-a-process-on-a-different-tty)